# Dask Bag read_text() line order

Tags: python, data-science, dask, bag

Does dask.bag.read_text() preserve the line order? Is it still preserved when reading from multiple files?

```
bag = db.read_text('program.log')
bag = db.read_text(['program.log', 'program.log.1'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally, yes, most Dask.bag operations do preserve order.

This behavior is not strictly guaranteed, however I don't see any reason to anticipate a change in the near future.