# Does dask.bag.from_sequence preserve order?

Tags: dask

I'm trying to determine if a `dask.bag` preserves order when instantiated using the `from_sequence` function.

I see from other questions that ordering is not guaranteed for a `bag` (e.g. [Dask Bag read_text() line order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652733/dask-bag-read-text-line-order)) but it's not clear to me why.
Does that mean "right now it's usually preserved for, say, lists, but we might have to change that because of something in the internals later"?

I ran the simple test below, in addition to testing on my complicated data structure. In both cases ordering does seem to be preserved. Just not sure if I need to do more, e.g., use `zip` to get a list of tuples of the form (index, object) and make my `bag` out of that, so I can sort by index after applying `compute`.

```py
from dask import bag as db
b = db.from_sequence([1,2,3,4,5])
sqr = lambda i: i**2
list(b.map(sqr))
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

An expected result would be that

```
list(b.map(sqr)) == [i**2 for i in [1,2,3,4,5]]
```

returns `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the linked answer seems to me clear enough: yes, order is preserved, but this is not guaranteed for the future. I would expect from_sequence to be one of the most likely to keep ordering, when passed something with inherent ordering (as opposed to random-access within a file or set of files). You can reckon on each item being processed once. Of course, where you have partitions and parallel processing, you cannot be sure *when* each item actually gets processed.

Comment: It is clear, I guess I was just hoping for more detail about why it can't be guaranteed for the future, so I have a better idea whether I should just put in extra code now to make sure it is preserved. For the time being I'll write a unit test that will break if ordering changes.